# jquery input autocomplete function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a auto complete feature that i found here on stack overflow [jQuery UI AutoComplete: Only allow selected valued from suggested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952094/jquery-ui-autocomplete-only-allow-selected-valued-from-suggested-list)

This is the jquery I'm using

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my implementation

```
<div id="ServiceProvider">
<h3 style="background-color:#EA6A20 ;"><b>Please enter the name of the HR representative who provided service to you</b> </h3>
<input autocomplete="on" type="text" name="HRName"  id="HRName" value=""></br></br>


<script>
var validOptions = ["First Last", "First1 Last1", "First2 Last2"]
previousValue = "";

$('#HRName').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});

</script>
</div>
```

The error i get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' Customer_Survery.php:266
(anonymous function) Customer_Survery.php:266
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: autocomplete is not part of jQuery, you need to include jQuery UI too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the library like this after loaded jquery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

An advise is to wrap it inside `document.ready()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var validOptions = ["First Last", "First1 Last1", "First2 Last2"]
  previousValue = "";

  $('#HRName').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
  }).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need jquery UI that contains the autocomplete plugin:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You should also include one of the following css:

[black-tie](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css), [blitzer](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.min.css), [cupertino](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css), [dark-hive](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.min.css), [dot-luv](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.min.css), [eggplant](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.min.css), [excite-bike](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.min.css), [flick](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.min.css), [hot-sneaks](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.min.css), [humanity](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.min.css), [le-frog](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.min.css), [mint-choc](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.min.css), [overcast](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.min.css),[pepper-grinder](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.min.css), [redmond](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css), [smoothness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css), [south-street](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.min.css), [start](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.min.css), [sunny](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.min.css), [swanky-purse](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.min.css), [trontastic](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.min.css), [ui-darkness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css), [ui-lightness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css), and [vader](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/vader/jquery-ui.min.css).

i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

Credit goes to [Downloading jQuery UI CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-ui-css-from-googles-cdn/820444#820444)