# Allow Only Selected Values From Dropdown List in Auto Complete Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need an autocomplete feature that allows a user to only type/choose from the list of values from a DB table.  I do not want them to be able to enter free text after the reason is selected.

I have referred to a similar posting [jQuery UI AutoComplete: Only allow selected valued from suggested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952094/jquery-ui-autocomplete-only-allow-selected-valued-from-suggested-list])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952094/jquery-ui-autocomplete-only-allow-selected-valued-from-suggested-list) but I have a different issue.

The challenge is the list of acceptable options have special characters, specifically `"("` and `")"`. When I type an option with ( I can see it in the drop down but when I use the arrow keys to select it will go to the previous option.

The array of acceptable options from PHP are accessed in javascript using

```
var validOptions = <?php echo json_encode($validOptionsArray); ?>;
```

The javascript is

```
previousValue = "";

$('.getValidOptions').autocomplete({
    source: validOptions,   

}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false; 
    for (i in validOptions) {
       if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue;
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
```

I understand how this is happening. If I remove the line

```
this.value = previousValue;
```

it will allow me to select the option with ( but then the user can continue typing.

However, I want to keep this line as it prevents the user from adding text to the dropdown.

I can use the mouse to select the option but I get an error in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/
```

So it seems the issue is related to keyup function

I have tried (1) charset="utf-8" and (2) regular expression such as

```
(this.value).replace(/([.*+?^=!${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks.

---

The data in the json_encode($validOptionsArray) is

```
Array
(
    [0] => NI: New Member
    [1] => NI: New Member (referred from current member)
    [2] => RI: Returning Member
    [3] => RI: Returning Member (with conditions)
    [4] => XI: Exclusive member (full/all access)
)
```

Comment: Can you please include the data that you get from `<?php echo json_encode($validOptionsArray); ?>` in your question.

Comment: Please see edit above. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewL64, any suggestions...?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with jQuery inputToken [http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/.)

It is easy to implement and allows the user to only select the available options and not edit them.  Maybe others will find this useful.