# search for item in long dropdown list with input filter, but only allow user to submit options from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a really long list in dropdown in my code (over3k+ options). Since my dropdown was so long I decided to use a datalist so the user can filter the dropdown easier with an input. This way they do not have to scroll through all 3k options.

I want to make it so the user can filter it, but CAN NOT enter/use a value that is not in the dropdown. I.E The input value will be an option from the dropdown or nothing. I'm not sure how to do this.

For instance they can type the colour John, but once they leave the input since John is not in the dropdown and they did not select it from the dropdown the value will be empty once they hit submit. However if they search blue and click blue, the input value will still be blue since it's in the datalist dropdown options.

Thanks in advance.

```html
   
   <form method = "POST">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="color"  list="colors_data" autocomplete = "off">
                            <datalist id="colors_data"style = "width:800px">
                              <option value="red"></option>
                              <option value="orange"></option>
                              <option value="green"></option>
                              <option value="blue"></option>
                            </datalist>
  <input type = "submit" value = 'send_request'>
  </form>
```

Comment: Have you considered something like [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: yup, I consider it. Was thinking about using it, however using that Jquery autocomplete I would still run into the same issue. The user will be able to select an option that is no in the autocomplete. I want it so that the user will only have an option in the autocomplete

Comment: You can lock it so the only option is to select from the autocomplete.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952094/jquery-ui-autocomplete-only-allow-selected-valued-from-suggested-list)

Comment: Do you want to submit the form if the value is not an option but with an empty string, or do you not want to submit the form at all?

Comment: @Andy I want the user to no submit the form at all.

Comment: @devlincarnate thanks I'll look into it

Comment: @devlincarnate another issue was that the autocomplete doesn't provide a dropdown when there's no input. You need to type something. I wanted it so that user can see all option when no input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab an array of all the colours from the option values and check if your input value is included.

```js
// Cache the elements
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('#color');
const submit = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');

// Add an click listener to the submit button
submit.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit, false);

// Iterate over the options with `map` and return a
// new array of colour values
const colors = Array.from(options).map(el => el.value);

function handleSubmit(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Check to see if the input value is included
  // in the colours array
  if (colors.includes(input.value)) {

    // If it is submit the form
    console.log('Found');
    // form.submit();
  } else {

    // Otherwise do nothing
    console.log('Not found');
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="color" list="colors_data" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="colors_data" style="width:800px">
  <option value="red"></option>
  <option value="orange"></option>
  <option value="green"></option>
  <option value="blue"></option>
</datalist>
<input type="submit" value='send_request'>
```

Note, if you didn't want to write out all that HTML you could build the options programmatically using an array, and using template strings to create the markup. Then you don't have to grab a separate array of colours to check against because you already have one.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];

// Iterate over the colour array to produce an array of strings
// that you then join into one string
function getOptions(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => `<option value=${el}>${el}</option>`).join('');
}

// Grab the datalist element
const datalist = document.querySelector('datalist');

// And insert the options
datalist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getOptions(colors));
```

```html
<datalist />
```

Additional documentation

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)