# How to retrieve the selected value from jQuery Autocomplete control

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textbox

My code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ab;
$(function() {
        $.getJSON('jsonSample.action',null,function(json) {
            ab = json.languageList;
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                  data:ab
              });
              });
    });
    </script>
```

This code works fine, when i start type in textbox where i have implemented this, displays all suggestion, now the problem is **i want to trigger a another event** as soon as one value is selected from suggestion list... And also another question is **How to get the selected value** as soon as the user select from autocomplete list..

I referred the tutorial which is in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797969/jquery-autocomplete-verify-selected-value)

```
 $(".tags").change(function(me) {
        alert(this.valu);
    });
```

This code displays the value what i typed in textbox, it is not displaying what the item i select in autocomplete..

I used another method ;

```
$(".tags").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        var u = this;
        // Check value here

    });
```

When i check it with firebug , it says there **no method found** ....  I want to show the item selected from auto populated list and also it have to trigger another event after i selected an item...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you provide the link to the autocompleter you are using?

Answer (score 0):

First off, looks like you are mixing an id selector `#tags` with a class selector `.tags`.

You need to refer to the object consistently (all should be `#tags`).  This should solve your problem.

Also, consider using jQuery's `.live()` method for the objects that appear in the suggestion list to assign a click handler to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "select" event, and access the ui.item.label for the selected value:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    select: function(evt, ui) {
        alert("Selected: " + ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Regards.